# How to find the intersection of two given lines

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find intersection of two lines below:
$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
3x − 2y & = & 5\\
7x + 3y & = & 4
\end{array} \right .
$$
I know the answer is $(1,-1)$, but I cannot find it with the methods. I have already tried to solve pairs of linear equations.

Comment: The answer is $(1,-1)$. And what are the methods you know?

Comment: http://www.mathcaptain.com/algebra/simultaneous-equations.html Answer: $(1,-1)$

Comment: Not very helpful answer. I need to know how. Did you use the substitution or elimination method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to equal any variable's coefficient in both eqn,either x or y.I take y to equal the coefficient.multiply 1st eqn by 3(2nd eqns y variable) and 2nd eqn by 2(1st eqns y variable)
$$
(3x − 2y  = 5)\cdot3$$
$$(7x + 3y  =  4)\cdot2 
$$
now eqn will be:
$$
9x − 6y  = 15$$
$$14x + 6y  =  8 
$$

now add both eqn side by side
$$9x − 6y +14x + 6y  =  15+8$$
$$23x=23$$
$$x=1$$
put this value of x in any eqn .I am taking 2nd eqn.
$$7\cdot(1)+3y=4$$
$$7+3y=4$$
$$3y=4-7$$
$$3y=-3$$
$$y=-1$$
so answer will be x=1 and y=-1 this is called elimination method

Comment: Thanks man. I actually did that way. I just wrote the 8 as a 9. Thanks for the help Man.

Comment: @Dantalion your welcome buddy.we are here to help each other

Answer (score 0):

Express your system in matrix notation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&-2\\
7&3
\end{array}
\right)\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5\\
4
\end{array}
\right)$$
Now mutliply both sides by the inverse of the matrix, which is the matrix
$$\frac{1}{23}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&2\\
-7&3
\end{array}
\right)$$
You finally get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: what if somebody doesn't know how to multiply or take inverse of a Matrix?